# Cannot use "Imports" in vbhtml file

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, namespaces

I try to add a namespace to my viewfile (vbhtml) in an mvc project. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239006/how-to-import-a-namespace-in-razor-view-page) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789578/namespace-reference-in-net-mvc3-razor-view-in-vb) solution it is straight forward using `@Imports NamespaceName`. Unfortunately this is not working in my case. My auto-generated (`strongly typed view`) file looks as follows:

```
@ModelType MVC_AdminTry1.Models.Employee
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code
<h2>Index</h2>
```

I cannot use the Imports command. Or at least `IntelliSense` does not give me any support. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789578/namespace-reference-in-net-mvc3-razor-view-in-vb. Doesn't answer your specific question but the answer I posted may help if the import statement doesn't appear to bring in your extension methods.